# sed - Add quotes to string after a certain symbol

Tags: bash, sed

Let's say I have a file with the following inside it;

```
size=large    
color=red
```

I wish to place quotes around `red` -- but not the line as a whole.

How can I use sed to put single quotes around whatever is after the `=` sign, but *only* in regards to the value of `color`?

As the actual value of color can be different each time in my scenario, this needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute `color=` followed by anything. Add quotes around the *anything* part:

```
sed -E "s/(color=)(.*)/\1'\2'/"
```

I enabled extended regex with `-E` so I don't need to escape the parentheses around both capture groups.

Comment: I think, you need to use `\1` and `\2` instead of `$1` and `$2` to backreference the group.

Comment: alternate: `sed '/color/ s/[^=]*$/\x27&\x27/'`

Answer (score -2):

Try to use such command

```
sed "s/=(.*)$/='\1'/"
```

Comment: When using *basic* regex, you need to escape the parens, e.g. `sed "s/=\(.*\)$/='\1'/")`

Comment: This also performs the substitution on all lines, not just the one starting with "color".